# Appending HTML to end of body using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have several templates for faceboxes (lightbox) that I need at different points of the application. These are stored in different partials and files.

I will initialize different javascript functions in accordance to which ones I need. The question is, what is the best way to append the external HTML page into my body using javascript?

Answer (score 15):

Since you tagged the question with it, here's a jQuery solution.

```
$("body").append("text");
```

Remember that the parameter can also be a DOM element. So you can do this :

```
var p = $("<p/>").text("a paragraph");
$("body").append(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way with jQuery is:

```
$('#result').load('test.html');

<div id="result"><!--/ Hold My Data! /--></div>
```

obviously you can change **#result** with **body**

Comment: thanks! this was super helpful. any idea how this can be done in in rails? it is often a partial (_partial.html.erb), which cannot be called as ("/partial")

Comment: If you want to load those partials dynamically with js, you'll have to expose each of them with a route. Replace `test.html` with `/path/to/my/action/to/render_partial`. Alternately, if you know you'll need them, render the partials into the view and hide them with  `display:none;` until you use them in your facebox.

Comment: Read This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229811/load-partial-with-jquery-and-rails AND this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484958/rails-ajax-jquery-problem

Answer (score -1):

Also you can try some templates library..
Like handlebar and underscore..

and append in the el provided by backbone.js

Answer (score -2):

Suppose you want to append this html in your template, then you can use the below code according to your application
Consider the code

**Example 1:**

```
rowData += '<div style="width: 130px;">'+param1+'</div>';
rowData += '<div style="width: 130px;">'+param2+'</div>';
$('#ID').html(rowData);
```

and please make sure that the js should be include in that file.
Here is the information of variable used above:

**row data** - the html that you want to append,

**param**- if you want to show the value of java script variable on browser dynamically,

**#ID**- ID of the div in which you want to append this html

**example 2**:
Consider the following HTML:

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<div class="user">
  <div class="inner">Hi</div>
  <div class="inner">Bye</div>
</div>
```

You can create content and insert it into several elements at once:

```
$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>" );
```